# Multiple grouping in a tablix

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012, ssrs-grouping

[image: I have a data set something like this.]

I Need to create Report something like this.
[image]

Took a tablix, inserted category then added a row group by category as group header. Then sub-category as category.
I am able to get till Amount, however stock and piece are not in (category & sub-category group span). I am not able to get after amount field. 
Please give some workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a tablix with the following Row Groups settings.

[image]

Add a column to the right side of `Subcategory` and select Inside the Group for `Amt`.

[image]

For Piece sum add a column to right side of `Stock`.

Also delete the details group and hide the details column by right clicking on it and going to `Column Visibility`, select Hide.

You will get the expected result:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me :)